# django ImageField link doesn't show in html template

Tags: python, django, profile

I can redirect to uploaded image through admin-panel but I can't load it on page. In HTML source code it looks like this:

```
<img src="" height = "200" with = "200" />
```

So here's my code:

models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/users/', verbose_name='Аватар', default = 'images/users/ava.gif/')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

from mainpage.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    #other urls
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/<<path to django app dir>>/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

template:

```
{% block content %}
    <body>
        <h1>{{ user.username }}</h1>
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ profile.avatar.url }}" height = "200" with = "200" />
        <p>
            <ul>
                <li>email: {{ user.email }}</li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </body>
    {% endblock %}
```

Will be very thankful for any help.

Comment: This won't fix your issue but there's a typo in "width", you wrote "with".

Comment: Are you sending anything called `profile` to the template? Show your view.

Comment: No there's nothing called "profile" in the views.
Should I write the view to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do is check the HTML generated by your code.

I don't think you need the {{ MEDIA_URL }} as profile.avatar.url should include the full url if you have your media settings correct.

```
<img src="{{ profile.avatar.url }}" height = "200" with = "200" />
```

Comment: Whats being output in the html? It would help a lot knowing that.

Comment: Just as I said in the OP, in the output there is no source link in quotes:

Comment: <img src="" height = "200" with = "200">

Comment: OK, so are you passing profile to the template in the view? Usually you do this in get_context_data().

Comment: No, but I' passing the User model. Should I pass one field of the Profile modile in the view? Will it be redundantly?

Comment: then it should be {{ user.profile_set.first.avatar.url }}  assuming that you expect one profile per user. 

Maybe you should be using a OnetoOneField instead of a ForiegnKey  field between profile and user - or do you want a user to have multiple profiles?

Comment: Many thanks, changed user field to OneToOneField and it helped.
Didn't really knew the difference between OneToOneField and ForeignKey, but now it is more clear for me. Thank you for advice.