# How to Create and Save File in Django Model

Tags: python, django

I have a view which generates a .docx file for whichever 'reference #' the user selects - I would like for the file to save to my Orders model whenever the doc is generated.

models.py

```
#model where I'd like to save the doc each time it gets generated
class Orders(models.Model):

    reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"This reference id has already been used"})
    ultimate_consignee = models.ForeignKey(Customers, blank=True)
    ship_to = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    vessel = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    ...
    order_file = #not sure what data type to use here
```

views.py

```
#view generating the .docx
def docjawn(request):

    reference = request.POST.get('Reference_IDs')
    referenceid = reference
    manifest = Manifests.objects.all().filter(reference__reference=referenceid)
    order = Orders.objects.get(reference=reference)

    doc = DocxTemplate("template.docx")
    totalCNF = 0
    totalFOB = 0
    for item in manifest:
        totalCNF += item.cases * item.CNF
        totalFOB += item.cases * item.FOB
    context = {

        'ultimate_consignee' : order.ultimate_consignee,
        'reference' : order.reference,
        'ship_to' : order.ship_to,
        'terms' : order.terms,
        'date' : "12",
        'ship_date' : "7/4/19",
        'vessel' : order.vessel,
        'POE' : order.POE,
        'ETA' : order.ETA,
        'booking_no' : order.booking_no,
        'manifest' : manifest,
        'totalCNF' : totalCNF,
        'totalFOB' : totalFOB,
}


    doc.render(context)

    doc_io = io.BytesIO() # create a file-like object
    doc.save(doc_io) # save data to file-like object
    doc_io.seek(0) # go to the beginning of the file-like object

    response = HttpResponse(doc_io.read())

    # Content-Disposition header makes a file downloadable
    response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=generated_doc.docx"

    # Set the appropriate Content-Type for docx file
    response["Content-Type"] = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

    return response
```

Ok so when the view above is accessed the system should generate the file and save it to the Orders model WHERE reference = reference_id.  Is this possible? Any suggestions? I really have no idea how to start trying to connect the two.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru this isn't exactly a duplicate - I don't want the user to have to upload the file.  I want the django app to generate the file using the view I have, but to somehow amend that view to save it directly to the model without any further intervention from the user.

Comment: Can't you just add a `FileField` to your `Orders` model and then save the file-like object you've generated to the appropriate model instance before you return a response from the view? I've done something similar where I generate a PDF file using `wkhtmltopdf` and then save that file to a `FileField` in a model before the view returns. In your models you said you weren't sure how to create the `order_file` model field. If you want to save a file to your `MEDIA` and be able to have a reference to it in the model, then `FileField` seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru could you possibly show me an example of how to do this in my view above? I agree a FileField seems to be the way to go after looking at that, but how can I make sure that the document corresponds to the correct reference_id?

Comment: Well, you have a part of the view that I assume gets the correct `reference_id` from the POST request, and then gets the corresponding `Orders` object. So you can save your doc file to that object's `order_file` field at some point in the view. I'm not quite understanding how your code works though, because `order` is only defined if it's a POST request, and all the rest of your code isn't in that block and refers to `order`. Is it that somewhere in a different view you make a request to this one and expect the file to be saved to your DB and also prompt the user to save it?

Comment: @MihaiChelaru ahh yes you're right I'm realizing this is a little sloppy. It functions like this: there is a view where there is a dropdown of all reference ids. user selects one, submits, calls the view above, and a doc is generated. I have edited above to remove that if POST. I just need to understand how to save the file to that object's order file I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like your view is quite close to doing what you want. In your model, add a `FileField` for `order_file`:

```
class Orders(models.Model):

    ...
    order_file = models.FileField(upload_to='path/to/storage/', null=True, blank=True)
```

Then in your view, save the `BytesIO` object you've created to the `order_file` field in the `Orders` object with the correct `reference_id` by wrapping it in a `File` object:

```
from django.core.files import File

def docjawn(request):

    reference = request.POST.get('Reference_IDs')
    manifest = Manifests.objects.all().filter(reference__reference=reference)
    order = Orders.objects.get(reference=reference)

    # Generate doc file
    ...

    doc_io = io.BytesIO()
    doc.save(doc_io)
    doc_io.seek(0)

    # Save the BytesIO to the field here
    order.order_file.save("generated_doc.docx", File(doc_io))

    response = HttpResponse(doc_io.read())
    response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=generated_doc.docx"
    response["Content-Type"] = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

    return response
```

Comment: thank you for the help - I am getting an error with the line ```order.order_file.save(filename="generated_doc.docx", File(doc_io))``` the error reads: "non-keyword arg after keyword arg" - could you advise on how to correct this?

Comment: Oh, apologies, that's because if you specify the argument as a keyword argument with `filename=` you can't have the next one without that. You can change it to `order.order_file.save("generated_doc.docx", File(doc_io))` and it should work. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Awesome that generated the file and saved it! But now I can see the file in the admin page but when I try to display it in the UI, say as a part of the table and I reference ```{{ orders.order_file }} ``` only the text of the file path shows up, I can't actually open it from the UI. Am I missing something there?

Comment: What I mean is that in the table, when I use that reference, I’d like there to be a link so I can open the doc. That works from the admin panel but not the UI

Comment: This is really a different question than what you asked originally. You should not ask multiple disjoint questions in the same thread. That said, I think you need [`{{ orders.order_file.url }}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739363/django-imagefield-link-doesnt-show-in-html-template) in your template in whatever `<a>` tag you're using as a link to open the file. Let me know if my answer solved your initial question, and consider giving it an upvote and [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).